# How do I record upvotes and page views in my database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I am designing a forum and I want to be able to let users upvote certain posts and I would like to record the amount of views that each post has so that I can display them to the public. I am primarily working with mysql, php, javascript, and jQuery. Typically when a user clicks on something that I want to record in the database I use jQuery to check the data, then php to input the data in the mysql database; however, this method requires the page to reload and that is definitely not what's happening on FB or Stackoverflow's website. I know that you can write to the database using jQuery or javascript, but everywhere that I have read about such things they advise against it for security purposes. So how should I go about this? Also, while were already here, if anyone could advise on certain precautions that should be taken in order to safeguard against abusing the upvote system. I was planning on limiting it to registered users and having a table that saves each users upvotes so that they can't upvote something more than once.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Put some effort into a solution and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on AJAX.  The only security precautions are basically just validating your input, same as you should be doing for your forms or any other input from a request.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you read online that it is not good to post data to the server via ajax, jquery, JavaScript I would disregard. Any site from here on out that offers any type of value what so ever will be written with clients that are loaded with JavaScript.

Even with posting the entire page, "the traditional way" to the server and collection data from form values you still run the risk of random users up-voting more than once, or commenting on your forum with spam.

The key is to make sure that everyone has an account so you can authenticate everyone that visits your forum. There is no reason to ever think that website users should be able to post anonymously to your forum.

Answer (score 0):

After researching more I cam across this little gem...Thank you to everyone who responded.

[How can I use jQuery to run MySQL queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598659/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-run-mysql-queries?rq=1)